# Is there any alternative to Jackson @JsonTypeInfo annotation

Tags: json, jackson

Friends,

Jackson framework provides annotation based approach to emit the type information during serialization process.

I do not want to use **@JsonTypeInfo** annotation in any of my class.

Is there any alternative/s to above annotation.

If yes, please provide example of to do the same if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Override JacksonAnnotationIntrospector and use your Introspector in your ObjectMapper by using setAnnotationIntrospector. Here is a code snippet for your AnnotationIntrospector:

```
@Override
public TypeResolverBuilder<?> findTypeResolver(MapperConfig<?> config,
        AnnotatedClass ac, JavaType baseType) {
    if (Modifier.isAbstract(baseType.getRawClass().getModifiers())){
        StdTypeResolverBuilder typeResolverBuilder = new StdTypeResolverBuilder();
        typeResolverBuilder.typeProperty("@class");
        typeResolverBuilder.inclusion(As.PROPERTY);
        typeResolverBuilder.init(Id.CLASS, null);
        return typeResolverBuilder;
    }
    return super.findTypeResolver(config, ac, baseType);
}
```

Comment: ``typeResolverBuilder.init(Id.CLASS, null);`` should be done before ``typeResolverBuilder.typeProperty("@class"); typeResolverBuilder.inclusion(As.PROPERTY);`` otherwise it does not work.

Comment: This prints a weird format for collection types, so I replaced `Modifier.isAbstract(baseType.getRawClass().getModifiers())` with `baseType.isAbstract()` and it definitely did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of alternatives:

- Use [mix-in annotations](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html) which do not require modifying of value classes
- Override `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and implement your own logic for determining when and how equivalent type information should be used.