# jackson polymorphic deserialization for non-abstract parent class

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

This is similar to [jackson polymorphic deserialize for non-abstract parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646684/jackson-polymorphic-deserialize-for-non-abstract-parent-class) but I can't use **@JsonTypeInfo** annotations because the serializaled JSON I can't change in my scenario.

```
public class Animal{
// Animal details
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
//Dog details

}

public class Cat extends Animal{
//Cat details

}
```

But there is a little problem: because my parent class (Animal) is not abstract, Jackson just deserializes all jsons into Animal class and while it does that, it fails because some of the fields present in child classes is of course not present in it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297050/is-there-any-alternative-to-jackson-jsontypeinfo-annotation ?

Comment: I think its just providing an alternative way for writing @JsonTypeInfo without annotations, still in the serialized json the type will be required to be passed unlike my usecase.

Comment: ok. can you elaborate how you would distinguish a dog or a cat from a general animal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842029/how-to-do-duck-typing-with-jackson looks like its more similar -- seems like this has not been successfully solved yet.

Comment: Dog and Cat can be distinguished with some fields, e.g dog has a doesBark field whereas cat doesn't have it BUT has doesMeow.. so based on the difference in fields, I want to differentiate.